# Which DNA test(s) is(/are) currently suitable for East Asians?

Tags: dna, asia

I think and believe that I am an East Asian .

I've browsed to find out which DNA test(s) is(/are) suitable for East Asians but I have not found one yet.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say whether you have considered AncestryDNA but the autosomal DNA test available from that company can be  used to look for [East Asian Ethnicity](https://www.ancestry.com/dna/ethnicity/asia-east):

> People in this DNA ethnicity group may identify as: Russian, Chinese,
> North Korean, South Korean, Mongolian, Vietnamese, Burmese (from
> Myanmar), Japanese, Taiwanese, Filipino, Indonesian, Thai, Laotian,
> Cambodian, Singaporean, Bruneian, Palauan